# How to flatten grouped Spark RDD contents as individual lines then save to file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD[(Int, Iterable[Coordinates])] that has been grouped by key (index: Int). Coordinates is a class with the members:

> latitude: Double, longitude: Double

I would like to create print or create a csv file, that would be in the following form (a row for each datapoint):

```
index,latitude,longitude
```

With the non-grouped RDD[(Int, Coordinates)] it worked like this:

```
val textOutputRDD = initialRDD.map(
  f => f._1.toString() + "," + f._2.latitude.toString() + "," + f._2.longitude.toString())
textOutputRDD.saveAsTextFile("TextOutput")
```

How do I manage to do that in this case?

Comment: What version of Apache Spark are you using?

Comment: @stefanobaghino 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple nested loop will do. Here I approximate coordinates with a simple pair of doubles:

```
val rdd =
  sc.parallelize(
    Seq(
      1 -> Seq((4.1, 3.4), (5.6, 6.7), (3.4, 9.0)),
      2 -> Seq((0.4, -4.1), (-3.4, 6.7), (7.0, 8.9))
    )
  )

val csvLike =
  for ((key, coords) <- rdd; (lat, lon) <- coords) yield s"$key,$lat,$lon"

for (row <- csvLike) println(row)
```

This code will result in the following output:

```
2,0.4,-4.1
2,-3.4,6.7
2,7.0,8.9
1,4.1,3.4
1,5.6,6.7
1,3.4,9.0
```

## Edit

Another possible approach is to swap in the actual `flatMap`/`map` sequence the compiler would turn the `for` comprehension into:

```
rdd.flatMap {
  case (key, coords) =>
    coords.map {
      case (lat, lon) => s"$key,$lat,$lon"
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, both with my own rdd and copied yours to try, results in the same error: value withFilter is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Seq[(Double, Double)])]. Tried to find a fix but with no luck.

Comment: I ran this successfully in the `spark-shell`, my best guess is that you are missing some `implicit`. Can you try swapping in this line instead of the loop and see what happens? It's semantically equivalent, in fact the compiler actually translates the loop into this: `rdd.flatMap { case (key, coords) => coords.map { case (lat, lon) => s"$key,$lat,$lon" } }`

Comment: I see a warning when using the `for` variant but no error. Are you by chance compiling with the `-Xfatal-warnings` compiler flag enabled? In any case, the `flatMap`/`map` variant should solve the issue.

Comment: Don't know if I'm looking in the right place, but my compiler's additional parameters are just `-Xsource:2.11 -Ymacro-expand:none`. Anyway, that fixes it! I had to make some changes still, because the coordinates are its own class, so the final row is: `classification.flatMap { case (key, coords) => coords.map { case (coordpair) =>  val lat = coordpair.latitude; val lon = coordpair.longitude; s"$key,$lat,$lon" }}`

Answer (score 2):

Try flatmap-

```
val output = rdd.flatMap(s=>{
      val list=List[String]()
      for (latlon <- s._2) {
        list.addString(s._1.toString() + "," + latlon.latitude.toString() + "," + latlon.longitude.toString())
      }
      return list
    })
output.save(....)
```

Comment: Could not get the list to work with this, however printing it, `println(s._1.toString() + "," + latlon.latitude + "," + latlon.longitude)` works as intended. Additionally, addString needs a StringBuilder as first parameter and output should probably be saved with `output.saveAsTextFile(....)`. Thanks for your input though, the flatmap works!